# template specialisation for a whole set of parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Possibly easy to solve, but its hard to find a solution to this:

Is it possible to (partially) specialize for a whole set of types?
In the example "Foo" should be partially specialized for (T,int) and (T,double) with only one template definition.

What I can do is define a specialisation for (T,int). See below. But, it should be for (T,int) *and* (T,double) with only one function definition (no code doubling).

```
template <typename T,typename T2>
struct Foo
{
  static inline void apply(T a, T2 b) 
  {
    cout << "we are in the generic template definition" << endl;
  }
};

// partial (T,*)
template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, int >     // here something needed like T2=(int, double)
{
  static inline void apply(T a, T2 b) 
  {
    cout << "we are in the partial specialisation for (T,int)" << endl;
  }
};
```

Any ideas how to partially specialize this for (T,int) and (T,double) with one template definition?

Comment: How could the compiler possibly know what to do here?  How would it know that you'd want to print `"partial double"`, etc.?

Comment: The output is meant only for knowing which function definition was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then you can write a base class template and derive from it, as illustrated below:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Foo_Base
{
  static inline void apply(T a) 
  {
    cout << "we are in the partial specialisation Foo_Base(T)" << endl;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, int> : Foo_Base<T, int> {};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, double> : Foo_Base<T, double> {};
```

Although its not one template definition (as you asked for), but you can avoid the code duplication.

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/s4anA

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately you used a circumstance that was applied in the original question, which was not intended this way. "Both" types are needed as function parameter. Sorry, I wasn't specific on that.

Comment: @Frank: Now see my answer. Now `Foo_Base` expects two type arguments and therefore I pass them when deriving from it

Comment: Nice idea! You are right. It is not one definition, but avoids code doubling. For the case being it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do this using Boost's [enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/enable_if.html) to enable the partial specialisation for just the types you want. Section 3.1 shows how, and gives this example:

```
template <class T, class Enable = void> 
class A { ... };

template <class T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<is_integral<T> >::type> { ... };
```